# Conclusion about cardinalty.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Assume that:
$$\left| T \right| > {\aleph _0}$$

Why can't one assume immediately that:
$$\left| T \right| \cdot \left| T \right| > \left| T \right| \cdot {\aleph _0}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For infinite cardinals $\kappa, \lambda$, we have:
$$
\kappa \times \lambda = \max(\kappa, \lambda) \text{ and, therefore } \\
\kappa \times \kappa = \kappa \text{ for $\kappa$ infinite}
$$

In this case, $|T|\cdot |T| = |T|$. Also, $|T|\cdot \aleph_0 = \max(|T|,\aleph_0) = |T|$. So in particular, $|T|\cdot |T| \not > |T|\cdot \aleph_0$, 
$|T|\cdot |T| = |T|\cdot \aleph_0$,

Comment: Just mentioning that you assume AC in your explanation; that is not needed to refute the given claim.

Answer (score 3):

Because assuming the axiom of choice, if $T$ is infinite then $|T\times T|=|T|\cdot|T|=|T|$.

Comment: But we do not need choice here: We cannot conclude the inequality, because $\mathfrak c$ contradicts it.

Comment: @Andres: Also $\aleph_1$.

Comment: So, definitely not an issue of choice.

Comment: Of course. But it is consistent with the failure of the axiom of choice that this is true for *some* $T$.

Answer (score 3):

The simpler counterexample: we have $2\gt 1$, but $|2\cdot\aleph_0|\not\gt |1\cdot\aleph_0|$.  The main 'reason' behind this is that the usual proofs that $a\gt b\implies ac\gt bc$ for $a, b, c\in\mathbb{N}$ use the finiteness of $a, b, c$ in an essential fashion: they assume that a whole number cannot be put into 1-1 correspondence with any of its proper subsets (this is what '$\gt$' denotes, after all).  This assumption breaks down when we get out of the finite realm; in fact, it's one of the *definitions* of infinitude.

Answer (score 1):

All that follows is that $\left| T \right| \cdot \left| T \right| \ge \left| T \right| \cdot {\aleph _0}$.
For example, if $|T| = 2^{\aleph_0}$ then $\left| T \right| \cdot \left| T \right| = \left| T \right| \cdot {\aleph _0}$.